# What is the industry standard model for pricing Swaptions during this time of negative interest rates, normal model or shifted log-normal model?

Tags: swaption, lognormal, negative, normal

I have referred to the some of the well known papers but none of them has a clear answer for my question. I know that both of these models have some disadvantages but, what is the industry standard for pricing derivatives? I need this information for pricing CVA.

Comment: I found a reference stating the CVA approach suggested by the BASEL regulatory framework. Any one interested can refer to https://www.d-fine.com/fileadmin/user_upload/pdf/insights/whitepapers/d-fine_Impact_of_the_new_CVA_risk_capital_charge_2019.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You may find this text helpful: [*Modern SABR Analytics : Formulas and Insights for Quants, Former Physicists and Mathematicians* by Alexandre Antonov, Michael Konikov, Michael Spector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZB5CSKT).

> Focusing on recent advances in option pricing under the SABR model, this book shows how to price options under this model in an arbitrage-free, theoretically consistent manner. It extends SABR to a negative rates environment, and shows how to generalize it to a similar model with additional degrees of freedom, allowing simultaneous model calibration to swaptions and CMSs.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. So, I assume SABR model is used the most to price swaptions in the industry? I thought it might be shifted log normal or normal model for the Black-76 model is widely adopted to price interest rate derivatives.